# How to point the cursor to result when search by 'let @/ = '?

Tags: search, register

To reproduce this problem:

1. Open a new vim window, input "abc", leave cursor at the end of line
2. `set hlsearch`
3. `let @/ = "abc"`
4. The cursor doesn't point to the beginning of "abc"

When searching by */*, the cursor always points to the match result when typing, how to do that with `let @/ =`  ?

Comment: does pressing 'n' suffice?

Comment: Changing `@/` changes the search pattern. It doesn't search anything. Note. I'd say `N` instead of `n`.